# I want to copy the path of mingw in system variables, but there is no extra path line shown

Tags: windows, mingw, system-variable

I have Windows 10 Pro operating system. I want to copy the path of mingw in system variables, but there is no extra path line shown here. What to do?

[image: there is no new path line here .what should I do]

Comment: is the regular screen capture not working on your computer

Comment: read your OS docs on how to modify PATH, watch the little `;` characters